# PowerShell 5.0 create variable of type Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType NVarCharMax

Tags: powershell

I cannot find the right syntax to create a variable of this type.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO')

$test2 = New-Object DataType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType NVarCharMax)
$test2.GetType().Name
```

Above results in an error

Comment: `SqlDataType` is an enum type, it exposes it's various members as _static_ properties (meaning you'll need to use the static member access operator `::`): `$test2 = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType]::NVarCharMax`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks, do you happen to know what assembly should be loaded? `Cannot find type [[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType]::NVarCharMax]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`

Comment: The containing assembly is `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll`, so `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` should do the trick :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Got an error about not being able to locate file, I tried syntax which works without Add-Type `$test2 = new-object('microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.SqlDataType::NVarCharMax')`. The issue I am facing now, when I assign a string value to the variable it turns into a datatype String. I need it to stay NVarCharMax. How can I turn a string into the SqlDataType::NVarCharMax?